# Extract all png files from a large txt file

Tags: file, text, split, binary, png

I have a really large txt file (80MB) that contains about 700 png files and I want to find a way to extract them.

All I know is that png files start with `‰PNG` characters and end with `` IEND®B`‚ `` if they open in a text editor and I believe if I find a way to store all strings between those characters in seperate files (including the start and end chars of course) I will achieve my goal.

But I have no idea how to do this considering the giant size of txt file. I tried Notepad++ to open the large file and it crashes due to its tremendous size.